# interpolating to a specific interval in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm plotting 2 sets of data (x,y) and (a,b). The x axis is at an interval of 0.05 for (x,y) and at an interval of 0.02 for (a,b). I'm trying to interpolate (x,y) so that it fills in data every 0.02 units. I've played with approxfun() and splinefun() but can't figure out how to work with the n or xout parameters properly.

```
require(graphics)
x<-c(1.00,1.05,1.10,1.15,1.20)
y<-c(4.1,6.4,8.4,5.2,0.5)
a<-c(1.00,1.02,1.04,1.06,1.08)
b<-c(5.0,8.3,7.3,4.0,6.0)

par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(x,y)
points(approx(x,y,method="linear"),col=2,pch="*")
plot(a,b)
```

Ultimately I want all of my vectors to have an x interval of 0.02 like (a,b) so that all of my vectors have the same number of elements, and save the new vector to a variable. I would also like to be able to switch back from 0.02 to 0.05, which I think would involve the same commands but switching the intervals? I think the words for what I want to do is resample my data to a new frequency.

I've looked in various threads for an answer to this, but I don't know enough about R to figure out how to ask this/search for it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow, but does `approx(x, y, method="linear", xout=seq(min(x),max(x),by=0.02))` do what you need?

Comment: Hi @thelatemail, yes this is what I need with regards to resampling to a new frequency. I need to look up the convention for what to do with the original pre-interpolated data as I'm trying to keep the vector sizes between (x,y) and (a,b) the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You may want to use a <-seq(1,10,by =.5), it increments by what ever factor you wish in this case .5